# parse field regex in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, parsing

I've a big table in my mysql db. In this table one column contain the metadata of all the content I've. the value is quite long and I need to extract the duration of all the video. this is an extract of the field:

```
{"progress":100,"id":"10","duration":4285,"audio":[],"status":"published" .....
```

I need to take care of the value after the "duration":

The value can start to 1 and be up to 10000.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
 substr, 
 LOCATE(':', substr) + 1,
 LOCATE(',', substr) - LOCATE(':', substr) -1) as duration FROM 
(SELECT SUBSTRING(column, LOCATE('"duration":', column)) substr
 FROM log_debug WHERE column REGEXP '\"duration\":')  as foo;
```

The inner select gets a substring that starts at 'duration' and spans to the end of the whole string, for all rows that have the duration field (add more conditions in the where if you want).

The outer select then gets a substring starting after the first ':' and ending before the ','

Comment: Hi Mamuso, thank you for your reply. Trying to run it (I have to add another where clause because of the huge quantity of rows) doesn't return nothing. then, once retrieved the value is it possible to sum it? thank you very much

Comment: Please update your question with the query you are making to see what may be wrong. To sum the durations, you only have to do SELECT SUM( SUBSTRING ... ) as total_duration FROM ...

Comment: Hi, I did it and worked like a charm. thank you very much.